# Is it appropriate to ask a sick student to leave the classroom?

Tags: teaching

Say you're teaching a class and a student shows symptoms of the common cold (cough, runny nose, etc.).

They might be contagious. Is it appropriate to ask them to leave?

Comment: For reference, if you have guests at your home and one of them shows symptoms of the common cold, how would you handle _that_ situation? I suppose a difference would be that the student is paying to attend, so the comparison isn’t quite right.

Comment: I think this heavily depends on the culture and thus, at the very least, on the country. @Aruralreader: *" that the student is paying to attend*" This also depends on the country.

Comment: If you could be sure the student had an airborne infectious disease, I'd be inclined to say yes; but the student may have privileged knowledge the instructor doesn't (and shouldn't), e.g. that they have a known non-infectious condition such as an allergy which could explain the symptoms.

Comment: I agree with @DanielHatton I had symptom of a common cold for 19 years now due to my allergy. While very mild most of the time, I have period where it is indistinguishable from a bad cold.

Comment: @JochenGlueck, yes, and in that case the comparison might be more appropriate. I agree there is a strong cultural aspect to this, and it would be clarifying to know how OP would handle it in other circumstances.

Comment: OTOH, Covid, with somewhat similar symptoms in some cases, remains very prevalent and very dangerous - so much so that I incline toward the view that it's irresponsible to be holding face-to-face classes at all until it's brought under control, although I'm aware that's very much a minority view.

Comment: I think Covid has shown that contagious infection shouldn't be ignored because of standing on ceremony. It can make a disaster. Some other students may have weak immune problem and get scarified. additionally, some may have someone with weak immune system at home. Asking one sick student to be out is better that forcing all others to choose between their course/life. You can later help the absent student to learn the courses which hasn't attended to the class. I also agree with @Buffy that it is better that universities make some rules for this,since some lecturers might have a different idea.

Comment: I’m pretty sure English _scarified_ isn’t what you intended.

Comment: I think the answer here has to be "Ask your institution. If you can't ask the institution, ask the community. If the community provides no guidance, decide what you want to do and ask the parents of the students in your class if that's OK with them." It *used* to be appropriate to send a kid to the school medical staff to be checked over, and have them make the recommendation and take the flack for it.

Comment: @Aruralreader (A link to such as [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scarify#Verb) would help those who aren't familiar with that fairly obscure word.)

Comment: Yes, please let every amateur make medical decisions whenever they want and wherever they want. Now you can pretty much ban anyone for whatever reason! You see the slippery slope right there, don't you? Of course you don't!

Answer (score 31):

Yes, it is appropriate unless you can have them mask and isolate somewhat from the others. Covid isn't gone yet and can have symptoms like those of a cold. But a cold can also be debilitating for some, especially those with any susceptibilities to other things.

Let them know, however, how you can bring them up to date for the missed lecture. Or have them contact you to obtain any needed information.

It is probably worth the effort to carry a few fresh N95 masks for such situations. It is probably also worth the effort for the university to have a published policy about this.

---

Edited to add: It probably isn't appropriate to "order them out" of the classroom. If they have evidence that the symptoms are not contagious then there is no need. But it is appropriate to ask them to leave or mask or take other precautions if they do, indeed, have a cold and are coughing or sneezing, possibly spreading infections. People need to take some responsibility for others around them.

If other students feel "at risk" from being around someone who might give them a disease then they might want to leave themselves. That is a bit harder to mitigate. And possibly more disruptive.

Comment: +1 for the policy from the university. While we are discussing about "asking" the student to leave and not forcing them, there's the possibility a student might feel like it is unfair and want to protest about the lecturer

Comment: And handling the request in as private a conversation as possible with the student would be appropriate.

Comment: @Carol, agreed, though it might not be entirely possible.

Comment: They may have a runny nose because they are allergic to pollen. They may cough because they smoke a lot. There are lots of possible reasons for cold-like symptoms and not all involve a contagious disease. "*If they have evidence that the symptoms are not contagious*" - will you ask them for a certificate from a doctor that they have asthma?

Comment: "If they have evidence that the symptoms are not contagious" Do keep in mind that in some jurisdictions, you're not allowed to just ask about medical conditions. In those jurisdictions you'll need a very good reason. Being scared they might infect somebody probably is not a good enough reason to ask for such proof.

Comment: @gaazkam - "Oh don't worry, I just have hayfever" is evidence that it's not a cold...

Answer (score 21):

In the UK, the [guidance for young people attending education settings](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/health-protection-in-schools-and-other-childcare-facilities/children-and-young-people-settings-tools-and-resources), including universities, is that people who have the symptoms you've described (*"cough, runny nose, etc"*) **should not be excluded as a matter of course**.

> *"Individuals with mild symptoms such as runny nose, and headache who are otherwise well can continue to attend their setting.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Children and young people settings: tools and resources](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/health-protection-in-schools-and-other-childcare-facilities/children-and-young-people-settings-tools-and-resources)</sup></sub>

If they have *additional* symptoms then they should be advised to stay off as a matter of course, and **can be temporarily excluded in an educational sense (e.g. ordered not to attend) if they do so**.

> ***Individuals should not attend if they have a high temperature and are unwell.***
>
> *Individuals who have a positive test result for COVID-19 should not attend the setting for 3 days after the day of the test.*
>
> [Individuals should not attend if they have] *Flu (influenza) or influenza like illness.*

Comment: "Cough" doesn't seem to be listed here.

Comment: @Buffy - That would come under the heading of a "mild symptom". Unless they're coughing up blood or *can't stop* coughing, in which case they're "unwell".

Comment: Actually, I don't think so. Coughing spreads droplets, etc. Sneezing is worse, of course.

Comment: This is depressing. Around March 2020, everyone agreed that one permanent change in society would be that people who had these kinds of symptoms would stay at home and not go to school/work - because (among other reasons) it was obvious that If people had done that from February 2020, many lives would have been saved. And then huge numbers of people died, more than anyone expected. But now people seem to have forgotten all that and believe that not even the simplest and easiest public health measures are worth taking.

Comment: @Buffy - Children are taught to [cough into their elbows](https://www.facebook.com/PublicHealthSCC/videos/cough-into-your-elbow/278017266692572/) nowadays, alleviating most of the worst effects of airborne disease-spreading. It's surprisingly effective.

Comment: Coughing into the elbow is effective only if it is universally practiced at each instance. It requires actions. Masking is more passive and can protect others.

Comment: @toby544 unfortunately the huge over reaction to the pandemic meant sensible changes like the one you posit have been lumped in with all the other nonsense and now consigned to history.

Comment: @deep64blue - Indeed. Children and young adults suffered almost no deaths as a result of COVID. The greater injury (to mental health and educational development) was as a result of the lockdowns.

Comment: @Valorum just because few children or young adults died doesn't mean there weren't a large number of people who did die whose infection went via a child or young adult, or that locking them down was an overreaction

Comment: @deep64blue I expect you are right that some people think like that. But in some countries there was a huge under-reaction, or a disastrously misjudged reaction, leading to large numbers of avoidable deaths. So if we have another situation like 2020 I think doctors, people whose family members died from covid, and others will rightly argue that public health measures are essential.

Comment: @Valorum Yes, children and others suffered from the lockdowns. But let's not forget that millions of people died, and most of them were not very sick or close to death to start with. In the UK, the government only imposed lockdowns very reluctantly, when it was forced to (twice) by the threat of overwhelming amounts of sickness and death due to the virus.

Comment: @toby544 I wish that was true re the UK ...

Answer (score 16):

MY lived experience as a teacher is that the boundary between appropriate and in appropriate is less about what you do and more about how you do it.

It is usually appropriate to express concerns for the welfare of a student and to suggest that going to see the nurse might be a really good ideal, and that they could catch up on anything that they missed rather than forcing themselves to struggle on.

It's usually inappropriate to order a student with a cold out in case they infect other students. Or you.

The way that you make the suggestion is everything.

Answer (score 14):

Please be careful about singling out students based on perceived symptoms.  Some students, for example, may have seasonal allergies that will manifest as cold-like symptoms (cough, runny nose, etc.) for several months in the spring and/or fall.  Students may also have a persistent cough for other reasons, such as a previous illness, asthma, chronic bronchitis, or acid reflux.  If you are concerned about a student's symptoms, make sure to raise the issue privately, and try to avoid an accusatory or annoyed tone until you have all the facts.

In addition, please be aware that it may not be practical for students who have small children to avoid attending class when they have a respiratory infection.  For example, the first year that each of my children started going to day care they brought home a new cold every few weeks for six months.  I'm sure these were contagious viruses, but it's not really practical to stay home for months on end to avoid spreading colds.

Comment: It is practical to mask, however, as is done in much of Asia in such circumstances and has been for a long time.

Comment: @Buffy That is certainly true, and I think it's very reasonable to ask students who have a respiratory infection to mask.  However, students who have seasonal allergies or other persistent conditions should not be expected to mask just because they are exhibiting symptoms.

Comment: Your answer describes colds. Your comment is about other things.

Comment: @Buffy The first paragraph of my answer is about other things, and the second paragraph is about colds.

Comment: During the pandemic of Covid, some infected people just claimed to have allergy at the time of coughing in public. Many didn't like to believe that they got infected and consequently they persisted against others' advices. Some even were eager to go to public, not wearing mask,... because they see it as the acceptance of the infection.

Comment: @Buffy the problem is it's not appropriate to ask someone suffering from asthma to make it worse by wearing a mask.

Comment: @deep64blue there is no evidence that someone's asthma is made worse by wearing a mask